# Java Generic Methods Motivation

Tags: java, generics

I am reading a Java text book and the writer to show usefulness of generic types in methods use an example:

```
public class BoundedTypeDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(2, 2);
        Circle circle = new Circle(2);
        System.out.println("Same area? " +
        equalArea(rectangle, circle));
    }

    public static <E extends GeometricObject> boolean equalArea(E object1, E object2) {
        return object1.getArea() == object2.getArea();
    }
 }
```

This is a ridiculous example... I do not understand where is the usefulness of using generic type in this particular example cause we could use GeometricObject as the type of equalArea method's parameters

Comment: It's not a good example, no. :-) (Not without some context of where and why it's being used in the book.) But what's your actual question? "Is it a good example?" "What would be a better example?" "Why have generics?"

Comment: yes, you're right, this is not a good example. if think it is even a bad one, because using generics introduces unecessary complexity to the code, when they are not necessarily needed.

Comment: Someone didn't want to write `GeometricObject` twice, possibly.

Comment: `<E extends G> boolean equalAreas(List<E> list1, List<E> list2)` (that compares the areas of the corresponding list elements) would be a better example.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov then they should have called it `Shape` ;)